# Error trying to debug an app when having a system app with the same package installed in device?

Tags: android, debugging, signature

Imagine you have a mobile device with some default system apps and you want to update for one of those.

If you have a release app with the same signature than the system app, you're fine.

BUT!!...

What happen if you want to debug your app in-device? How could you run a debug app (when having a system app installed, with same package and a signature)?

How to proceed with this issue? Thanks to all.

(the error shown when trying to do this in image below)

[image]

Comment: What about using a different 'testing' package name?

Comment: Yes, it could be a possibility, although I would need to change packageName on all other apps as I'm using broadcast receivers for the communication. Thanks.